# Unexpected BoolQuery when compose search object and use $search->getQueries()

Tags: php, elasticsearch, dsl, ongr

I'm using the ongr/elasticsearch-dsl bundle to build my queries and I need to compose the search-object on different places. When I do it in the same place, it works as expected.

```
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Search;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\Compound\BoolQuery;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\TermLevel\TermsQuery;

$search = new Search();
$bool = new BoolQuery();
$search->addQuery($bool);

$bool->add(new TermsQuery('id', [1]));
$bool->add(new TermsQuery('id2', [2]));

echo json_encode($search->toArray());
```

The result look like this:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"id":[1]}},{"terms":{"id2":[2]}}]}}}
```

Now I pass the search-object to another method and try do add my TermQuery-Objects.

```
$search = new Search();
$bool = new BoolQuery();
$search->addQuery($bool);

$mapper->map($search);

//---
public function map(search) {
    $bool = $search->getQueries();
    $bool->add(new TermsQuery('id', [1]));
    $bool->add(new TermsQuery('id2', [2]));

    echo json_encode($search->toArray());
}
```

The result is almost the same, but with an extra and empty BoolQuery.

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":[]},{"terms":{"id":[1]}},{"terms":{"id2":[2]}}]}}}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or how can I extend my search and avoid that empty query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `BoolQuery`, when you add any query it will automatically form `BoolQuery`. More info here: http://docs.ongr.io/ElasticsearchDSL/HowTo/HowToSearch in "Multiple queries and filters" topic.

```
$search = new Search();

$mapper->map($search);

//---
public function map($search) {
    $search->add(new TermsQuery('id', [1]));
    $search->add(new TermsQuery('id2', [2]));

    echo json_encode($search->toArray());
}
```